# jQuery - Referencing psuedo/other class inside variable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Currently re-doing a script for a slider on my website and i've just stumbled upon something which i've wondered for a while - how do you say get the `:first-child` of `var element` if `var element = $("ul").children("li")` for example? Or in my case;

```
$(".slider").each(function() {
    var slider = $(this),
        nav = slider.children(".nav"),
        prev = nav.find(".prev"),     /* Trying to get other class from .nav */
        next = nav.find(".next");     /* Same as prev */
}
```

Am i working along the right lines here? It just cleans up code instead of occassionally having to re-reference `.nav` as a child of the `slider`.

**EDIT**

I'm referencing mine via `data-` attributes for `prev` and `next`, is there a way of doing;

```
nav.find("[data-nav='prev']");
```

Or won't that work?

Comment: what are you trying to do..? can you rephrase your question..?

Comment: In fairness (for once) i feel like i have made it quite clear, especially with the example i have provided. Felix managed to interpret what i was asking clearly enough.

Comment: Can you just share html? then anybody can understand more clearly

Comment: I'm not really talking about HTML. I'm talking about jQuery and how to re-reference a variable stored element. So in the first case, get the first child of the variable element, so if i then style the element it only styles the first child rather than ALL `li` elements within a `ul`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I am assuming in your html

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="nav next">NEXT</div>
  <div class="nav prev">PREV</div>
</div>
```

then if you have

```
$nav = $('.nav');
$next = $nav.filter('.next');
$prev = $nav.filter('.prev');
```

**ADDITION TO ANSWER**

You can also use `.filter()` to reference attributes such as `data-*=`, `name=`, `type=` and so on so forth.

Comment: This works, also the best bit is it works for finding attributes too. So say if you wanted to for example find all elements with `data-switch=1` using `.filter("[data-switch='1']")` this brings up the correct elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
element.find(':first-child')
```

Comment: That works for part A of the question in terms of finding the `:nth-child()` but what about if you want to select a specific class from within the same element?

Comment: @LeeB Then use `element.find('.class:first-child')`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that didn't work i'm afraid.

Comment: @Felix i just tried the code you recommended to see if that worked but it doesn't appear to be doing what i hoped it would.. I will just run through it again and see if i have any typos.